# Control horizontal scroll with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I'm working on a project and I'm stranded and i decided to ask you for help

I have 2 Divs

1- Div that stores content with full width

2- Div that simulates a scrollbar, which will make scrolling of the first Div

below my project image
https://prnt.sc/n1vyg5

100% functional example
https://www.udacity.com/course/blockchain-developer-nanodegree--nd1309
in the session "Learn with the best"

The structure is similar to this

```
.page {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}

h3 {
  background: #dbd0bc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.hs {
  list-style: none;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20% 2rem 20%;
}

.hs .item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 17rem;
  background: #dbd0bc;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0.75rem;
  height: 10rem;
  white-space: normal;
}

.scrollbar {
  width: 100%;
  background: #bcc9d4;
  height: 0.2rem;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3rem 0 3rem 0;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  height: 0.2rem;
}
.handle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 0.7rem;
  background: purple;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 2rem;
  top: 1px !important;
}
```

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="container">
    <h3>Container</h3>
    </div>

    <ul class="hs">
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="scrollbar">
        <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.handle').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    containment: 'parent',
    drag: function (event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.position.left)
    }
});
```

I do not know how to synchronize the drag of the '.handle' with the scrolling of the first div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do some calculation on the width of scrollbar and the width of scrolling content. Then decide how much is the percentage of the left position of scrollbar and pass it to the scroll percentage of content. I made all calcuations on window load to make sure that the size of elements are final:

```js
$(window).on("load",function(){
    var scrollbarWidth=$(".scrollbar").width();
    var handleWidth=$(".handle").width();
    var remaining=scrollbarWidth-handleWidth;
    var hsWidth=$("ul.hs")[0].scrollWidth- $("ul.hs")[0].clientWidth; 
    var percent;

    $('.handle').draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        containment: 'parent',
        drag: function (event, ui) {
        percent=(ui.position.left/remaining);
        $("ul.hs").scrollLeft(percent*hsWidth);
   }
});

})
```

```css
.page {
overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
width: 60%;
margin: auto;
}

h3 {
background: #dbd0bc;
color: #000;
padding: 1rem;
}

.hs {
list-style: none;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 100%;
padding: 0 20% 2rem 20%;
}

.hs .item {
display: inline-block;
width: 17rem;
background: #dbd0bc;
text-align: center;
margin-right: 0.75rem;
height: 10rem;
white-space: normal;
}

.scrollbar {
width: 100%;
background: #bcc9d4;
height: 0.2rem;
position: relative;
margin: 3rem 0 3rem 0;
border-radius: 2rem;
height: 0.2rem;
}
.handle {
position: absolute;
width: 30%;
height: 0.7rem;
background: purple;
cursor: pointer;
cursor: -webkit-grab;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
border-radius: 2rem;
top: 1px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="page">
    <div class="container">
    <h3>Container</h3>
    </div>

    <ul class="hs">
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="scrollbar">
        <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, it works, only remaining left the double way, when scrolling the content in a native way, fiddle with the div that simulates the scrollbar

Comment: in fact there is some error in your calculations, I just do not know what ...

content is coming to an end before '.handle' reaches the end

Comment: OK! I had to omit the clientWidth from total width of `hs` and did it! @YungSilva